# MIxed Content bug requesting font stylesheet with Next js

Tags: reactjs, http, https, fonts, next.js

I'm trying to add font to my website through Nextjs in a React component but getting the following error :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/page/subpage' was loaded over HTTPS,
but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://allfont.net/cache/css/bookman-old-style-bold.css'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error since I'm making a https request via the Head like so:

```
import Head from "next/head";
export default function page() {
   return (
      <Head>
        <link
          href="https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=bookman-old-style-bold"
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
        />
      </Head>
  )
}
```

Comment: Go to https://allfont.net/cache/css/bookman-old-style-bold.css directly in browser, and you can see the line `url(http://allfont.ru/cache/fonts/bookman-old-style-bold_7fd13e86ae699e2e0b704fa09098f17d.woff)` in loaded CSS. It has `http`, not `https`. This might be the reason of **Mixed Content**. Here is a workaround: you can download the font files from http://allfont.ru/cache/fonts/bookman-old-style-bold_7fd13e86ae699e2e0b704fa09098f17d.woff and http://allfont.ru/cache/fonts/bookman-old-style-bold_7fd13e86ae699e2e0b704fa09098f17d.ttf and simply write the font-face style in your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the http, but still looking for a solution without downloading the font files

Comment: I don't think there would be any other solution. You can contact allfont team using https://allfont.net/contact/ and tell them this issue. They can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://allfont.net" />
            <link
                href="https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=bookman-old-style-bold"
                rel="stylesheet"
                type='text/css'
            />
```

Comment: adding <link rel="preconnect" href="https://allfont.net" /> did not solve the issue

Comment: try this
`<link rel="preconnect" href="https://allfont.net" crossorigin />`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).